# Pushing back a pointer to a vector and then modifying its value affects the pushed value. What should i do instead?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I am using pointers in c++ to achieve polymorphism and I store pointers to the derived classes into a vector. Changing the value of a stored pointer affects the value of all the copies of the same pointer, as it should, however i would like to modify the value of each object individually. Is it possible?

**Main class**

```
#include "Cat.h"
#include "Dog.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<Animal*> animalVector;

  Animal* animal;
  animal = new Dog();

  animal->setDescription("Good Dog");
  animalVector.push_back(animal);

  animal->setDescription("Bad Dog");
  animalVector.push_back(animal);

  animal = new Cat();

  animal->setDescription("Good Cat");
  animalVector.push_back(animal);

  for (auto& it : animalVector) {
    it->info();
  }
}
```

**Base class**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using std::string;

class Animal
{
  protected:
    string mType; //! Holds the type of the Animal
    string mDescription; //! Holds the description of the Animal

  public:

    Animal();
    virtual ~Animal();
    virtual void info();

    virtual void setDescription(string description) {mDescription = description;}
};
```

**Derived class**

```
#pragma once

#include "Animal.h"

class Dog : public Animal
{
  public:
    Dog();
};
```

**Output**

```
Bad Dog
Bad Dog
Good Cat
```

**Desired output**

```
Good Dog
Bad Dog
Good Cat
```

Comment: Missing `animal = new Dog();` before `animal->setDescription("Bad Dog");`.

Comment: FWIW I'd use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>` because it would save you having to clean up the pointers manually later.

Comment: You start by pushing two pointers to the very same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you modify the same object `Dog`, you need to create new instance before you set description for "Bad Dog" and you have memory leak in your program.

So you better use smart pointers, either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on type of ownership you need:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animalVector;

animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Dog>());
animalVector.back()->setDescription("Good Dog");
animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Dog>());
animalVector.back()->setDescription("Bad Dog");
animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Cat>());
animalVector.back()->setDescription("Good Cat");
```

and if you set description for every animal, you should pass to it constructor, then it would be even cleaner and shorter:

```
animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Dog>("Good Dog"));
animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Dog>("Bad Dog"));
animalVector.push_back( std::make_unique<Cat>("Good Cat"));
```

Comment: If you have a lot parameters to set on the pointed object and then you just want to create a new object with only slight modifications with respect to the previous one, you can also consider implementing `Animal* Animal::Clone();` interface.